# Is it rude to fix a date of appointment with a professor after one week?

Tags: etiquette, professionalism

I am undergraduate student and am applying for internships to professors in the United States. One professor replied to my email and said - "Thanks for your email! Lets have a zoom call" to which I replied that it would be convenient for me to schedule a date after a week since my semester exams would end by that time and after that I would be free at any time. Was it rude of me to schedule a date that far away and did I leave a bad impression? Should I have scheduled something more immediately? Does my reply show that I am not really dedicated to working with him or I am bad at efficiently managing my time and scheduling my multiple tasks together?

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it is rude if you say it in a nice, respectful and professional way to the professor.

All professors understand that the highest priority of a student is to study well for the final exams. They will likely accept a new date for the interview that fits both their schedule and yours.

Comment: I replied - "I have a series of semester course exams starting from this Friday (<date>) that will last till next Friday (<date>) so it would be great if we could do it after that, preferably any time during week after that. In case you think an earlier date might be preferable for you, let me know and I would try to go by that. "... Do you think its okay?

Comment: @Harmonic, That sounds great to me.

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully its just me overthinking it, and I haven't managed to annoy my prof on the first interaction

Comment: @Harmonic, Best of luck. :-)

Comment: Yes, that was a good response. Not rude at all.

Comment: @Buffy Thanks! Although I am yet to hear back from him... Maybe I should email him again once my exams are over